# change the feature delegation in IIS 7 - command line

Tags: iis

Hi is there any way to change the feature delegation so that all delegations are Read/Write in IIS 7 via the command line?

Or even the command line to change one. I ahve searched online but so far I cannot find anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<CustomAction Id="QtExecHandlers_Cmd" Property="QtExecHandlers" Value="&quot;[SystemFolder]inetsrv\appcmd&quot; unlock config /section:handlers" Execute="immediate"/>

<CustomAction Id="QtExecHandlers" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no"/>
```

Comment: Simple version: appcmd unlock config /section:handlers